# Issue with receiving HTTP with Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: apex, rest-api

I've faced a strange issue during my development related to the API. My goal was to create a web service that will receive POST requests from different sources.

First service:
It passes all the necessary data as the URL parameters. It has `Content-Type : application/json` and the empty body. There were no problems with it.

Second service:
Here starts an interesting part. 
This service passes all the necessary parameters in the request body and has the `Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. 
This request always returned 401 error - Unauthorized.
I've managed to figure out what exactly makes this request to crush.

The body of the request looks like: 
`originalsenderid=%2B614XXX11XX1&body=This%20is%20a%20test%20message&message=This%20is%20a%20test%20G3C7FWKNOD.`

If the body parameter has spaces (%20 or +) I'm getting a 401 error - Unauthorized.

If the body parameter has no spaces, like `body=Thisisatestmessage` everything works fine. Spaces in other parameters also accepted as expected.

What is important here that this issue is reproducible only with `Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. 
If I change it to `Content-Type : application/json` it also works fine. But I have no access to the request creation, so I can't customize the request.

Also, I am using the Public RESTful Web Service as described [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/02/quick-tip-public-restful-web-services-on-force-com-sites.html).
I tested it with the simple web service like this:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/messageService')    
global class ReceiveData
    {
        @HttpPost
        global static void doPost()
        {
            RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
            System.debug(req);
        }
    }
```

One more note - when I'm getting the issue with 401 error my endpoint is not even launched.

I'm not sure what additional info I should provide. I'm developing via scratch orgs so the link to my endpoint will be not valid soon.

Update:

endpoint that also reproduces an issue:

https://poormansorg-developer-edition.eu17.force.com/test/services/apexrest/myservice

Debug log looks like this:

[image]

Update2:

During the investigation I've noticed that this issue also reproducible only when you public domain has the additional pass specified. For example:

- this one will return error:

https://poormansorg-developer-edition.eu17.force.com/test/services/apexrest/myservice

- this one works fine:

https://poormansorg-developer-edition.eu17.force.com/services/apexrest/myservice

Maybe someone faced similar issues or can point me where my mistake is?

Comment: I just tried with `Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and passing the contents in the `body` as in your post, and everything seems to work fine. Does the request make to your `doPost()` method?

Comment: @JayantDas no it doesn't. I've reproduced the same issue on my dev org. I updated the post with the endpoint

Comment: 401 would mean unauthorized access, i.e., not valid client credentials. But if you are able to get the response by just changing the content-type, then I wouldn't imagine that to be the case. As mentioned at least I was not able to reproduce this and it works perfectly fine with what you have described here.

Comment: @JayantDas  I'm not using authorization at all. It is a public web service. I tried to reproduce this on several dev and scratch orgs and the behavior is always the same

Comment: is it force.com site?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal yes

Comment: Have you added class `ReceiveDataClass` to force.com site user's profile?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal yes, of course. I am able to process other request

Comment: @AndreyShkolnikov can you change name of `body ` param to something else in your reqyest? like param1 etc?

Comment: the `body` being special keyword in HTTP specification this is working weirdly.
I tried your endpoint `https://poormansorg-developer-edition.eu17.force.com/test/services/apexrest/myservice` and provided a `key` as something other than body and it works

Comment: I tried hitting the endpoint as in your question with the content-type as x-www... and the body contents exactly as mentioned, and received a 200 OK response.

Comment: @Pranay Jaiswal I don't have access to the request creation

Comment: @Jayant Das are you using public endpoint on a force.com site?

Comment: I used the endpoint that you have in your question.